# Restful : How to get access to Httpsession inside the Service class?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey restful web services .
This is my below code

```
@Path(/test)
public class testService  {
    @POST
    public String getData(Postdata postdata) {

    }

}
```

My question is , is it possible to get access to httpSession Object here in this class ??

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try:

```java
@POST
public String getData(Postdata postdata, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
}
```

Comment: what is '@Context ' annotation..? is it spring..?

Comment: It's a JAX-RS annotation: https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Context.html

Answer (score 22):

If your service is NOT singleton, you can use:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource  {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @POST
    public String getData(Postdata postdata) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to retrieve a HttpServletRequest at runtime? Via the ServiceLocator or some other way?

Comment: Hi, @zwanz0r In runtime? I do not understand what you mean. Do you want to say using JAX-RS?

Comment: Well.. i have a spring injected bean, i.e. SessionUtil, in which i want to access the HttpSession. I don't want to be passing through the jersey injected HttpServletRequest every time I access the session util.

Comment: OK. Then @zwanz0r you may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629211/how-do-i-get-the-session-object-in-spring :)

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work at first because I got this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039522/getting-a-no-thread-bound-request-found-error-from-spring-in-my-web-app. After I added the listener class RequestContextListener, it worked. Now I can also let spring inject the request. Just 2 questions:
- Can I simply add a second listener class without consequences?
- Can I let spring inject the servlet request? As the spring bean is a singleton and request should obviously not be a singleton (when i use reflection is see that the actual class is a proxy, which is hopeful)

Comment: After a few tests and reading documentation i found that it is actualy save. Sorry for my 'stupid' questions, i'm still new in the java world :). Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PaulVargas: I can easily get request object in resource class, But I don't want to pass that request object to subsequent method each time, So my question is How can we get request object in any normal java class(Any helper, wrapper class)?
I am using (struts 2 + jersey)

Comment: @U2Answer You can try with `ThreadLocal`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5473312/870248

Comment: Thanks!, Is there any ready Jersey Implementation class which tackle this ThreadLocal etc etc and help to get current request object where we want.

Comment: @U2Answer Humm... nope. See `https://github.com/jersey/jersey/search?utf8=✓&q=ThreadLocal&type=Code`

Comment: Thanks! So i have to manually store request in ThreadLocal from ContainerRequestFilter

Comment: Paul, can you please answer my question about sessions and RESTs. Is not it that rests are stateless, and we must not have sessions on it? Even if RESTs are based on servlets should we have opportunity to have an access to session object?

Comment: @Dante Yes! You can access to the session object. BTW, what is your question?

Comment: Paul, please follow  the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful
First answer, author said: "In server perspective, it is designed to be entirely stateless and self-contained on a per-request basis (i.e. there are no sessions)."
And you are telling that get access to sessions - is ok, so i am little confused to be honest

Comment: By ***design***, yes!, it must be stateless. ***But***, since JAX-RS is servlet-based, you can access to the session object, like a normal servlet, using the `request` object. You can do things like [this](https://gist.github.com/paul-vargas/d693b9a09645db1e6b9d000a6100f4ba). Awesome!

Comment: How can we know that is my service singleton or not?