# Tapestry Session Object on a non page class (REST class)

Tags: rest, session-state, tapestry

I am using Tapestry for my web project and have a question about sharing a `Session Class` to a non `Page class`.

I have class named `VisParser.java`. I want to create that class for *every* session and use it in an `RestImplementationclass`. `VisParser.java` is not a model class. It is a simple Java class with methods and attributes.

I tried to use the `SessionState` object annotation, but I could not transfer the object to a non-page class. Every time it throws a `NullPointerException`.

I tried to use it as a service class, inject it on a page and try to call it with getters and setters. No Success, still throws a `NullPointerException`.

I think the source code is not necessary.

A little hint would be enough. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Source code is always necessary ;-) You're probably doing something wrong in your order if you use getters and setters and you're still seeing an NPE. The source code is the only place to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an older question with solution, which solved my problem.

[Restful : How to get access to Httpsession inside the Service class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831042/restful-how-to-get-access-to-httpsession-inside-the-service-class)

Thanks anyway. :-)