# Using ThreadLocal to store HttpServletRequest and response

Tags: servlets, thread-local-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ThreadLocal to store ServletRequest and Response in servlet: what for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473077/threadlocal-to-store-servletrequest-and-response-in-servlet-what-for)

I have a servlet class which sends information to some Delegator class which later invokes some Business Service methods.

I need the current HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects to the Delegator class's methods. Instead of keeping it as part of the method signature, I thought about setting that in a ThreadLocal variable from servlet class and later retrieving it from the ThreadLocal variable in Delegator class's methods.

Below is the sample code.

```
//Servlet class
    public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{        
        protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException,IOException{
           Utils.setHttpServletRequest(request);
           Utils.setHttpServletResponse(response);  
        }

    }

                             //******Utils class*************
public class Utils {
public static final ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest> servletRequest = new ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest>();

public static final ThreadLocal<HttpServletResponse> servletResponse = new ThreadLocal<HttpServletResponse>();

    public static HttpServletRequest getHttpServletRequest(){
        return servletRequest.get();
    }

    public static HttpServletResponse getHttpServletResponse(){
        return servletResponse.get();
    }

    public static void setHttpServletRequest( HttpServletRequest request ){
        servletRequest.set( request );
    }

    public static void setHttpServletResponse( HttpServletResponse response ){
        servletResponse.set( response );
    }
}

//Delegator clas

public class TestClass{
       public void testMethod(){
          //IS THIS CORRECT?
          HttpServletRequest request=Utils.getHttpServletRequest();
        }

}
```

Could you please suggest if there can be any possible issues with this approach?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473077/threadlocal-to-store-servletrequest-and-response-in-servlet-what-for