# Catch httpServeletRequest in loadUserDetails method

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have a customized spring `AuthenticationProvider` class but try to intercept the `HTTPServletRequest` and `HTTPServletResponse` within the `loadUserDetails` method.

```
@Component("darnGoodAuthenticaionProvider")
public class DarnGoodAuthenticaionProvider 
                    extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter 
                    implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService {
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
                            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) 
                            throws Exception {
            this.request = request;
            this.response = response;
            // we don't want anything falling here
            return true;
}

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication token)throws 
                                                    UsernameNotFoundException{
           .......
    }
}
```

I know the `preHandler` method from `HandlerIntercepterAdapter` is capable to the job but how can I be sure that the `preHandler` method is called prior to `loadUserDetails`, so that I can get the request and response prepared?

Thanks

Comment: `DarnGoodAuthenticaionProvider` is misspelled :)

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I don't think so, I use Urban Dictionary :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a servlet container, each request will be handled from the moment the request is received until the response is returned by only one thread (request == current thread).

So it's a matter of putting a servlet filter BEFORE the spring security filter chain (with the filter-mapping element above the filter-mapping of spring security), and storing the request and response in the thread using a `ThreadLocal` variable - see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473077/threadlocal-to-store-servletrequest-and-response-in-servlet-what-for).

Then on the `DarnGoodAuthenticaionProvider` access the request using a static method `RequestResponseHolder.getRequest()`.

**web.xml config:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>saveRequestResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>sample.save.request.filter.SaveRequestResponseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>saveRequestResponseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/mobilews/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Filter to save the request response in the thread:**

```
public class SaveRequestResponseFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        RequestResponseHolder.setRequestResponse(req,resp);
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        finally {
            RequestResponseHolder.clear();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
       ...
    }
}
```

**Request/Response holder:**

```
public class RequestResponseHolder {

    private static ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest> requestHolder = new ThreadLocal<HttpServletRequest>();
    private static ThreadLocal<HttpServletResponse> responseHolder = new ThreadLocal<HttpServletResponse>();


    public static void setRequestResponse(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        requestHolder.set(request);
        responseHolder.set(response);
    }

    public static HttpServletRequest getServletRequest(){
         return requestHolder.get();
    }

    public static HttpServletResponse getServletResponse()  {
        return responseHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clear() {
        requestHolder.remove();
        responseHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

**Obtaining the request from `DarnGoodAuthenticaionProvider`:**

```
HttpServletRequest req = RequestResponseHolder.getServletRequest();
```