# Access data computed in filter for each request inside Spring Controller/Service Class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In our application, all rest apis are of the form:

> http://{context}/{product_id}/{rest_url_path}

I have to verify the {product_id} inside a Spring Security Filter/SpringMVC interceptor, by fetching the `ProductDetails` from DB for the product_id. The `ProductDetails` will be used inside Spring Controllers/Service classes.

I don't want to fetch the `ProductDetails` again inside Controllers/Service. So I want to store the `ProductDetails` object somewhere for that `RequestScope`.

I have 3 approaches in mind. But each have their pros and cons. Please let me know which one better out of the 3. Also suggest any alternative approach.

**Approach-1:**

Save the `ProductDetails` object inside request attribute.
Inside Controller, i can easily get the `HttpRequest`. Inside Service, I can get `HttpRequest` by:

```
@Autowired
HttpServletRequest request;
```

or

```
RequestAttributes attribs = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
HttpServletRequest request = null;
if (attribs instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
    request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) attribs).getRequest();
}
```

But I don't want to have HTTP request dependency inside Service to make to code more independent from WebLayer logic.

**Approach-2:**

Use any in memory cache based on `product_id` to stored `ProductDetails`

But this I think a over kill only for this use case. Increasing unnecessary dependencies of a cache.

**Approach-3:**

Store the Object in a `ThreadLocal` variable to store request scope data.
But not sure if it correct this way.

Let me know an efficient approach to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

1st and 3rd are suitable for your problem statment but first one is more elegant as data will stored only for current request scope and will get automatically lost when server send response. You can also use threadLocal but you have to be cautious ,if you forget to remove object it will hang around in an environment that uses a thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach you mentioned is more efficient way to access the same data in both filter and controller even though you have to inject the dependency of HttpservletRequest in SpringController.

If the data is very user specific like other user will not have access to those data in that case you should use ThreadLocal.

Comment: For more information you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35444633/spring-how-to-pass-objects-from-filters-to-controllers . Which is a similar kind of usecase.

Comment: As per this above thread, i guess using `ThreadLocal` seems efficient. Also it says about using a `RequestScope Bean`. This seems much more efficient. I have to give it a try